# How to display error message when record not found in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, binary, binary-data

I created code for converting binary data to pdf my aim is to show error message when date is not avalable in sql otherwise it should pdf file can anyone help me how to do.

Comment: All what you need to do is to add condition to check the number of records returned by SqlDataReader... I believe you know how to achieve that.

Comment: Why don't you show the message on pdf file itself.

Comment: Can please update the code

Comment: do you want the message to be displayed on pdf?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the message on pdf itself then

```
Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
  if sdr.hasrows then
    sdr.Read()
    pdf = DirectCast(sdr("BinaryData"), Byte())
    ID = sdr("RunId").ToString()
  else 
    pdf = DirectCast("No Data Found", Byte())
  end if
```

Comment: I am getting this error values of type string cannot be converted into 1 dimensional array of byte in this line pdf = DirectCast("No Data Found", Byte())

Comment: try `DirectCast(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("No Data Found"), Byte())` I am not good in VB.net

Comment: if i do this it will show error in the PDF file i want to show in the aspx page like lblerrors or by validation

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this

```
Dim csname1 As String = "PopupScript"
Dim csname2 As String = "ButtonClickScript"
Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()

Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

If (Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1)) Then

  Dim cstext1 As String = "alert('Record not found');"
  cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1, True)

End If
```

You can also use the approach given here http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/executing-javascript-code-from-server

As you can see it will load the script, you either can load that script or can create a function and call it like VB example in telerik or Mix both approaches to suit you.