# Throw new application exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to throw an exception in asp.net VB web application using framework 2.0  my issue is  I only want to show the error message , but  using below code i also see line number, file  and other error messages.

Throw New ApplicationException("My error message ")

i have tried  the below code

Throw New ApplicationException("Insert Member Method Not Supported")

```
 Throw New ApplicationException("Insert Member Method Not Supported")
```

I want to show  My error message without line numbers or file name that it is in etc using  Throw New ApplicationException()  or an alternative that halt's further operation and displays a error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an error message in an ASP.NET Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651716/how-to-display-an-error-message-in-an-asp-net-web-application) Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344186/4934172) for VB.

Comment: That other information is called a "stack trace". Is there any reason why you don't want to see this?

Comment: I'm  delivering data to a third party legacy  fronted that doesn't do any handling for some reason.  My only option is to manually throw an error to send across an exception message eg " Incorrect password"

Comment: at Ahmed , That example doesnt help me understand how can i  raise a manual exception y self like  Throw New ApplicationException("Insert Member Method Not Supported")
  and than show it without stack trace.

Comment: @user3548161 I assumed you can handle the exception (i.e., try-catch) somewhere else in the code (or in the front-end). Why can't the exception be handled in the front-end? When an exception is thrown, it has one of two paths: either get handled or cause the application to crash.

Comment: ahmed I know how to use try catch normally but i dont know when using  Throw New ApplicationException("Insert Member Method Not Supported")
 can you give example